# how to set width of a div in percentage minus certain pixels using javascript or css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

following code represents two divs on my webpage.

```
<div class="left">Left</div>
<div class="right" id="toset">
   <div class="right-top">right-top</div>
   <div class="right-bottom">right-bottom</div>
</div>
```

i have two divs, left is of fixed width and position, the right one has to be of the remaining width and of absolute position .

i cannot figure out how to set the width of right one to fill the remaining screen.

check following link for the full code.

http://jsfiddle.net/X5Bd6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly,

```
.right{
        :
    right: 0px;
}
```

should do the trick.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zCGsb/).

Comment: thx thats worked fine...but can u plz xplain why was this important

Comment: That's a way how absolutely positioned element knows how to calculate its width.